# jQuery slideshow code won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm building a simple jQuery slideshow that I'm using for my website.

I found the code here (and did some adjustments): http://www.barrelny.com/blog/building-a-jquery-slideshow-plugin-from-scratch/ (my only requirements were that the code had to be built from scratch, be lightweight, use CSS3 Transitions and slide automatically every fifth second.)

The problem is, I can't even get anything to happen with my code. Anyways, here it is.

```
(function($){
function prefix(el){
    var prefixes = ["webkit", "moz", "o", "ms"];
    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
        if (prefixes[i] + "transition" in el.style){
            return '-'+prefixes[i].toLowerCase()+'-'; 
        };
    }; 
    return "transition" in el.style ? "" : false;
};
s    var methods = {
    init: function(settings){
        return this.each(function(){
            var config = {
                slideDur: 7000,
                fadeDur: 800
            };
            if(settings){
                $.extend(config, settings);
            };
            this.config = config;
            var $container = $(this),
                slideSelector = 'article',
                fading = false,
                slideTimer,
                activeSlide,
                newSlide,
                $slides = $container.find(slideSelector),
                totalSlides = $slides.length,
                $pagerList = $container.find('#control');
                prefix = prefix($container[0]);
            function waitForNext(){
                slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    changeSlides('next');
                },config.slideDur);
            };
            function animateSlides(activeNdx, newNdx){
                function cleanUp(){
                    $slides.eq(activeNdx).removeAttr('style');
                    activeSlide = newNdx;
                    fading = false;
                    waitForNext();
                };
                if(fading || activeNdx == newNdx){
                    return false;
                };
                fading = true;
                $pagers.removeClass('active').eq(newSlide).addClass('active');
                $slides.eq(activeNdx).css('z-index', 3);
                $slides.eq(newNdx).css({
                    'z-index': 2,
                    'opacity': 1
                });
                var styles = {};
                styles[prefix+'transition'] = 'opacity '+config.fadeDur+'ms';
                styles['opacity'] = 0;
                $slides.eq(activeNdx).css(styles);
                var fadeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    cleanUp();
                },config.fadeDur);
            };
            function changeSlides(target){
                if(target == 'next'){
                    newSlide = activeSlide + 1;
                    if(newSlide > totalSlides - 1){
                        newSlide = 0;
                    }
                } else if(target == 'prev'){
                    newSlide = activeSlide - 1;
                    if(newSlide < 0){
                        newSlide = totalSlides - 1;
                    };
                } else {
                    newSlide = target;
                };
                animateSlides(activeSlide, newSlide);
            };
            for(var i = 0; i < totalSlides; i++){
                $pagerList
                    .append('<nav id="control" data-target="'+i+'">'+i+'</nav>');
            };
            $container.find('#control').bind('click',function(){
                var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
                clearTimeout(slideTimer);
                changeSlides(target);
            });
            var $pagers = $pagerList.find('#control');
            $slides.eq(0).css('opacity', 1);
            activeSlide = 0;
            slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                changeSlides('next');
            },config.slideDur);
        });
    }
};
$.fn.easyFader = function(settings){
    return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
};
})(jQuery);
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7PLz/

I really hope somebody could help me - any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7PLz/1/) and now it works perfectly. Your problem, apart from a typo in the code (there was an 's' before 'var methods') and that you were executing the plugin function in the DOMready event handler and invoking it at the end of the body tag, was that your slides were arranged vertically inside the slideshow container. As the slideshow container has a specific height and overflow hidden, they were invisible. I changed that, setting the articles to position absolute so the articles ar now one upon the other. Besides, without position absolute or relative z-index doesn't work.

```
#slideshow article { 
  height: 345px; 
  width: 700px; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you help with me another thing? I want the previous slide to always have the CSS "left: -700px" and the next slide always "left: 700px" for a sliding effect that I want to build.

I have tried something like this: `function addCSS() { old = activeSlide - 1; new = activeSlide + 1; old.css('left', -700px); new.css('left', 700px); };`, but nothing happens - and I don't know where or how to put it, either.

Comment: What you mean is that, besides fading into the next slide, you want the slides to slide from right to left when advancing, and from lefto to right when going backwards? If you do that, animating the opacity might be odd, as there would be nothing under the current slide...

Comment: Yes, I am switching out the fade/opacity effect, and want a slide effect instead, just as you described. I'm going to switch out the opacity transition, but first I have to apply the CSS above. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Thanks, really! Remember, I only want to use CSS3 Transitions - and without a fallback code, because I don't need (or want) to support old IE versions. So the `transition` part would be something like this: `transition: transform...` referring to `transform: something`.

Answer (score 1):

I open a second answer to post the new code.

I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7PLz/3/), now the transition is a slide, and the code is simpler:

```
(function($){
function prefix(el){
    var prefixes = ["webkit", "moz", "o", "ms"];
    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
        if (prefixes[i] + "transition" in el.style){
            return '-'+prefixes[i].toLowerCase()+'-'; 
        };
    }; 
    return "transition" in el.style ? "" : false;
};
var methods = {
    init: function(settings){
        return this.each(function(){
            var config = {
                slideDur: 7000,
                fadeDur: 800
            };
            if(settings){
                $.extend(config, settings);
            };
            this.config = config;
            var $container = $(this),
                slideSelector = 'article',
                slideTimer,
                activeSlide,
                $slides = $container.find(slideSelector),
                $carousel = $slides.parent();
                totalSlides = $slides.length;
                $carousel.css('width', (totalSlides * 100) + '%');
                $pagerList = $container.find('#control');
                prefix = prefix($container[0]);
            function waitForNext(){
                slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    changeSlides('next');
                },config.slideDur);
            };
            function animateSlides(){
                $pagers.removeClass('active').eq(newSlide).addClass('active');
                var $slide = $slides.eq(newSlide);
                var offset = $slide.position().left;
                console.log(offset);
                var styles = {};
                styles[prefix+'transition-duration'] = config.fadeDur+'ms';
                styles[prefix+'transform'] = 'translate3d(-'+offset+'px, 0px, 0px)';
                console.log(styles);
                $carousel.css(styles);
                waitForNext();
            };
            function changeSlides(target){
                if(target == 'next'){
                    newSlide = activeSlide + 1;
                    if(newSlide >= totalSlides){
                        newSlide = 0;
                    }
                } else if(target == 'prev'){
                    newSlide = activeSlide - 1;
                    if(newSlide < 0){
                        newSlide = totalSlides - 1;
                    };
                } else {
                    newSlide = Math.max(0, Math.min(target, totalSlides - 1));
                };
                activeSlide = newSlide;
                animateSlides();
            };
            for(var i = 0; i < totalSlides; i++){
                $pagerList
                    .append('<nav id="control" data-target="'+i+'">'+i+'</nav>');
            };
            $container.find('#control').bind('click',function(){
                var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
                clearTimeout(slideTimer);
                changeSlides(target);
            });
            var $pagers = $pagerList.find('#control');
            activeSlide = 0;
            slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                changeSlides('next');
            },config.slideDur);
        });
    }
};
$.fn.easyFader = function(settings){
    return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
};
console.log('here');
```

})(jQuery);

You have to wrap the articles in another div with id 'carousel'.

Right now, when the slideshow reaches the last slide, it goes back to the beginning. If you want to always advance from right to left, and go back from left to right, it becomes a bit more complex. You could try [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com), that already allows you to do this, with many more options.

Comment: Sorry, the link was to a previous update of the fiddle. Refresh and load the fiddle again (it's the third version).

Comment: Thanks - it's working now. However, I would really like that on the last slide, it continues sliding the right way - that would be possible with the solution I posted - targeting the previous slide to **always** be `left: -700px` and the next slide to **always** be `left: 700px`. I don't want to use a plugin.

Comment: Could you help me more @Oscar, or do I have to do it myself? Thanks or your help anyways - you've been really helpful for sure.

Comment: I can, but not until tomorrow, sorry.

Comment: I've simplified and deleted a lot of the code without taking away the main functionality (now just 25 lines!) - the transition prefixes and pager can be implemented later. I've also  experienced some with the optimal slide transition that I want, and got it alomst working right. This is the minimal fade code: http://jsfiddle.net/b7PLz/4/

Comment: There is a difference between "tomorrow" and 8 days, @Oscar. But it's okay.